# Prototype AJAX Updater Multiple Requests

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I am just beginning to learn AJAX and am trying to build a cascading dropdown that pulls information from a database. My AJAX.Updater code works, but not only for one of the dropdowns.  How do I make multiple AJAX.Updater calls?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/prototypejs.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('#regiondropdown').change(function() {
  dropdowns(jQuery(this).val(),"foo");
  });

  jQuery('#foodropdown').change(function() {
  dropdowns(jQuery(this).val(),"bar");
  });

}
);

function dropdowns(str,type)
  {
      if (type=="foo") {
        new Ajax.Updater('foo', 'foo_dropdown.php', { method: 'get', parameters: {foo: str} });
      } else if (type=="bar") {
        new Ajax.Updater('bar', 'bar_dropdown.php', { method: 'get', parameters: {bar: str} });
      }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Just wondering why you wish to combine jQuery + Prototype. Either will do on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what it is so I suggest you fire up your debugger.
1) Check the value of jQuery(this).val() for both cases.  "this" might not be what you believe in Javascript.
2) Check what happens if you switch the if.. and else... in dropdowns.  Maybe there is a (, { or ; out of place.

HTH

Comment: I added alerts to check the values of the two jQuery(this).val() and they both return the expected values.  The strange thing is the second SELECT does not alert if it is selected after the first.  If you select the 2nd SELECT first, the alert is displayed.